# Prediction in R, error in code

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I'm having problem with running `predict()` in R. I created a linear model called `CopierDataRegression` and renamed the explanatory variable `X`. I'm supposed to predict `Y` when `X=6` and I used the following commands:

```
NewObs6 <- data.frame(X=6)

predict(CopierDataRegression, NewObs6)
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'V2' not found

What is wrong with the predict line code?

Full Code:

```
CopierData1 <- read.table("Ch1_20_data.txt")
# V1 is total number of minutes (explanatory) V2 is number of copiers serviced (predictor). 

CopierDataRegression <- lm(V1~V2, data=CopierData1)

plot(CopierData1$V2, CopierData1$V1)
Y <- CopierData1$V1
X <- CopierData1$V2
plot(X, Y)

NewObs6 <- data.frame(V2=6)
predict(CopierDataRegression, NewObs6)
```

Comment: It's probably due to renaming the variable. Either do `NewObs6 <- data.frame(V2=6)` or change the name of `V2` to `X` before running the regression model.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Do you know why this happened? Because when I used NewObs6 <- data.frame(X=6) and then called NewObs6 in the console, it output 6.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you changed the column name **after** you have fitted the model. That would result in the following behaviour:

```
df = data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = rnorm(10))
fit = lm(Y ~ X, df)
predict(fit, data.frame(X=3))
       1 
0.861924
# change the column name *after* creating the lm object
colnames(df) = c("A", "B")
predict(fit, data.frame(A=3))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X' not found
```

Therefore if you want to name the predictor variable `X` do so before creating the model. Remember that for `predict.lm` the column name of the `data.frame` you pass as argument has to match the name of the predictor you use in the `lm()` call.

Comment: But this does not seem to affect the plot function.


plot(CopierData1$V2, CopierData1$V1)
Y <- CopierData1$V1
X <- CopierData1$V2
plot(X, Y)

This actually plotted the data correctly. So, is it best practice is to first rename columns and then refer to that one name throughout the code or should I leave it alone and just be cognizant that the model and predict function both need the variable array to have the same name?